# How do you place a variable inside a template tag's argument?

Tags: django, django-templates

With Django media I could do the following:

```
{% for language in LANGUAGES %}
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}app/js/jquery.ui.datepicker.{{ language.0 }}.js"></script>
{% endfor %}
```

Now, I'd like to switch to static files. However this (obviously) does not work any more:

```
{% for language in LANGUAGES %}
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "app/js/jquery.ui.datepicker.{{ language.0 }}.js" %}"></script>
{% endfor %}
```

Is there some clean way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

[ I want to switch for consistency, because the admin and many third-party apps I'm using have switched. Also, I'm worried that the Django media will be deprecated sometime in the future. ]

Comment: Try with `{{STATIC_URL}}` instead of `{%static%}`

Comment: Is `LANGUAGES` a model or another Django related object?

Comment: If you dont want to use `STATIC_URL` you can create a simple_tag to achieve that for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options. First one, as suggested, use `{{ STATIC_URL }}`:

```
{% for language in LANGUAGES %} 
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="{{STATIC_URL}}app/js/jquery.ui.datepicker.{{ language.0 }}.js"
></script> 
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively, as `{% static %}` only prefixes its argument but does not require the path to be actually valid:

```
{% for language in LANGUAGES %} 
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="{% static "app/js/jquery.ui.datepicker" %}.{{ language.0 }}.js"
></script>                                 
{% endfor %}
```