# How to use variables in template tag arguments?

Tags: django, django-templates

I try to achieve the following:

```
<img src="/static/teammembers/some_name">
```

but if I write `<img src="{% static 'teammembers/{{ image }} %}">` in the template,
then the rendered output is

```
<img src="/static/teammembers/{{ image }}">
```

what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

In my case the solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220632/how-do-you-place-a-variable-inside-a-template-tags-argument?rq=1) does not work, since I use an automatic cachebuster (django-cachebuster).

Comment: possible duplicate of [django 1.5 - How to use variables inside static tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655851/django-1-5-how-to-use-variables-inside-static-tag)

Comment: @alecxe I don't think it is a duplicate, since the cachebusting breaks the answers there.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to offend you, looks like solution using `add` template filter is the way to go. Does it work for you?

Comment: you did not, and also thanks for the suggestion! I tried that and `<img src="/static/'teammembers/'|add:image?000000000000">` was the result. :(

Comment: ok, posted one option as an answer, hope it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`with`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with) with an [`add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add) template filter as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655851/django-1-5-how-to-use-variables-inside-static-tag):

```
{% with 'teammembers/'|add:image as image_static %}
    <img src="{% static image_static %}">
{% endwith %}
```